# Removing default message in mat-sort-header

Tags: angular, sorting, header

I am trying to remove the in-built message:

Sorted by value ascending/descending

in mat-sort-header. It comes up every time I click on the header for sorting. 
I am using angular 2. Here's the code that I am testing: https://material.angular.io/components/sort/overview

The message isn't shown in example but when I run it on my Pc, it's shown.

The sample code is as below:

HTML :

```
 <table matSort (matSortChange)="sortData($event)">
  <tr>
    <th mat-sort-header="name">Dessert (100g)</th>
    <th mat-sort-header="calories">Calories</th>
    <th mat-sort-header="fat">Fat (g)</th>
    <th mat-sort-header="carbs">Carbs (g)</th>
    <th mat-sort-header="protein">Protein (g)</th>
  </tr>

  <tr *ngFor="let dessert of sortedData">
    <td>{{dessert.name}}</td>
    <td>{{dessert.calories}}</td>
    <td>{{dessert.fat}}</td>
    <td>{{dessert.carbs}}</td>
    <td>{{dessert.protein}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

TS :

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Sort} from '@angular/material';

/**
 * @title Sorting overview
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'sort-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'sort-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['sort-overview-example.css'],
})
export class SortOverviewExample {
  desserts = [
    {name: 'Frozen yogurt', calories: '159', fat: '6', carbs: '24',         protein: '4'},
    {name: 'Ice cream sandwich', calories: '237', fat: '9', carbs: '37', protein: '4'},
{name: 'Eclair', calories: '262', fat: '16', carbs: '24', protein: '6'},
{name: 'Cupcake', calories: '305', fat: '4', carbs: '67', protein: '4'},
{name: 'Gingerbread', calories: '356', fat: '16', carbs: '49', protein: '4'},
  ];

  sortedData;

  constructor() {
    this.sortedData = this.desserts.slice();
  }

  sortData(sort: Sort) {
    const data = this.desserts.slice();
    if (!sort.active || sort.direction == '') {
      this.sortedData = data;
      return;
    }

    this.sortedData = data.sort((a, b) => {
      let isAsc = sort.direction == 'asc';
      switch (sort.active) {
        case 'name': return compare(a.name, b.name, isAsc);
        case 'calories': return compare(+a.calories, +b.calories, isAsc);
        case 'fat': return compare(+a.fat, +b.fat, isAsc);
        case 'carbs': return compare(+a.carbs, +b.carbs, isAsc);
        case 'protein': return compare(+a.protein, +b.protein, isAsc);
        default: return 0;
      }
    });
  }
}

function compare(a, b, isAsc) {
  return (a < b ? -1 : 1) * (isAsc ? 1 : -1);
}
```

CSS :

```
.mat-sort-header-container {
  align-items: center;
}
```

Screenshots of result:
[clicking on header 1st time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6R4i5.png)

[clicking on header 2nd time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2Ax1.png)

[clicking on header 3rd time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1ISR.png)

Comment: I can't see any message in example

Comment: Yea but when I am running it on my PC, it shows the message.

Comment: Please post the screen shot and also the code you have implmented

Comment: I have added. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are facing the issue , because you haven't added the theme's css

Add this style in your css and message will be gone :

```
.cdk-visually-hidden {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
}
```

> But I would suggest to **[FOLLOW THIS STEP](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started#step-4-include-a-theme)**

Comment: @VishwaPatel, Glad to know , please checkout the link also that's the proper way to go

Comment: Better solution to add the Angular-Material style to your default stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by importing any of the pre-built styles in your styles.css file.

Pre-built styles:
1. deeppurple-amber.css
2. indigo-pink.css
3. pink-bluegrey.css
4. purple-green.css

For Eg:

@import'~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';